# Lambdas calls speed changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudfront, throughput

I've created a simple lambda that reads data from dynamodb.

First time I call the lambda it takes about 1500ms to complete, but then after I run the lambda again it takes about 150ms. How is it possible?

What type of caching response does AWS preform to achieve this?

Comment: What language/runtime are you using?

Comment: I'm using Node JS 8

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda is provision infrastructure on your first call and it's required time also AWS needs to start a JVM with the code to be able to call the function. Starting the JVM takes time and thus will incur some overhead.

Another issue is cold ,if there is no idle container available waiting to run the code. This is all invisible to the user and AWS has full control over when to kill containers.

So above steps are involved  during first call and you can see 1500 ms
Next call you have everything on place so lambda give you response in 150 ms or less .

This is as per design of serverless to save infrastructure cost ,only provision infrastructure when needed and get first call.

I would suggest please read documents
- https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to cold start. This happens mainly when we invoke the lambda for the first time after deployment or when a lambda function is idle for sometime.

These articles explains about how language, memory or size of the lambda affects the cold start

https://read.acloud.guru/does-coding-language-memory-or-package-size-affect-cold-starts-of-aws-lambda-a15e26d12c76

https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/